# Chave estrangeira FK, é cada numero de identificação em uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, plpgsql

Exemplo:

> ```
>  - CLIENTE(Num_cliente, Nome_cliente, Cidade)
>  - PEDIDO(Num_pedido, Data_pedido, Num_cliente, Preco_total)
>  - ITEM_PEDIDO(Num_pedido, Num_item, Quantidade)
>  - ITEM(Num_item, Preco_unitario)
>  - EXPEDICAO(Num_pedido, Num_deposito, Data_envio)
>  - DEPOSITO(Num_deposito, Cidade)
> ```

Neste de caso as FK, são o numero do cliente, numero do pedido, numero do cliente, numero do item, numero do pedido,numero deposito existe alguma restrição nesse exemplo, alguém consegue ver?

Answer (score 1):

A chave estrangeira (Foreign Key) é quando uma chave de uma tabela (alguns chamam de índice, ou de ID) é usada dentro de outra tabela para referenciá-la, então ela existe para relacioná-las, ou seja, não existe sozinha.

No teu exemplo `NUM_CLIENTE` é chave estrangeira na tabela **PEDIDO** (faz referência ao cliente que fez o pedido) enquanto que `NUM_PEDIDO` é chave estrangeira nas tabelas **ITEM_PEDIDO** e também em **EXPEDICAO**. No caso da a tabela **ITEM_PEDIDO** ela tem *duas* chaves estrangeiras pois correlaciona as tabelas **ITEM** e **PEDIDO**.

A única restrição que vi no teu modelo tem relação ao fato de que um pedido pode ser enviado (expedido) de forma parcelada ou mesmo guardar um histórico sobre seu estado (pendente, enviado, devolvido etc).

Answer (score 1):

Esses que você citou são os candidatos a PK das respectivas tabelas... 
A FK é a chave que faz referência à outra tabela e, nas suas tabelas, são as que seguem em negrito:

CLIENTE(Num_cliente, Nome_cliente, Cidade)

PEDIDO(Num_pedido, Data_pedido, **Num_cliente**, Preco_total)

ITEM_PEDIDO(**Num_pedido**, **Num_item**, Quantidade)

ITEM(Num_item, Preco_unitario)

EXPEDICAO(**Num_pedido**, **Num_deposito**, Data_envio)

DEPOSITO(Num_deposito, Cidade)